# Is $f(x) = x^2$ an isometry?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

I am wondering if $f(x) = x^2$ is an isometry? My definition of an isometry is the following:

Let $(X, d)$ and $(\dot{X}, \dot{d})$ be metric spaces. $f: X \rightarrow \dot{X}$ is an **isometry** if:

$\dot{d}(f(x), f(y)) = d(x,y),   \forall x,y \in X$

For my question I would choose:

- $f(x) = x^2$
- $X = \mathbb{R}$
- $d(x, y) = |x-y|$
- $\dot{X} = \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$
- $\dot{d}(x,y) = ||\sqrt{x}|-|\sqrt{y}||$

It is also true that every isometry is injective. However, $f(x)=x^2$ is not injective which is clear.
Could you tell me what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example, take $x = -1$ and $y = 1$.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Think it works now.

Comment: Even if you only consider the positive numbers, it's still not an isometry. Choose, say, 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

$d(1,-1) = 2$

$\dot{d}(f(1),f(-1)) = 0$